# Scrollspy Implementation With MVC 4

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, scrollspy

I have a **web application based on MVC 4** framework with Bootstrap(twitter) and i want to make one of my pages a one page navigation with a scrollspy:

I have a fixed navbar at the top throughout my site and in one page of the site i want i addition a side bar ("nav nav-pills nav-stacked pull-left") with a scrollspy.

**col-md-3 =** on the left that will be storing my sidebar

**col-md-9 =** on the right that will be storing my context

I try different things and nothing seem to work, **one thing that i notice is 
that i need to add to the body tag:**

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target="#side-nav">
```

**but in MVC the body tag** is on the "_layout" and i don't want to touch this shared partial view.

What can i do ? maybe someone has implement this feature in MVC and could give me a small example of it ?

**This is my code :**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Designer";
}

    <div class="row">


    <div class="col-md-3">
        @* Index *@
        <div class="nav-pills pull-left affix navspy">
            <div id="side-nav">
                <ul class="nav">
                    <li><a href="#general">General</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#words">Words</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#filetype">File Type</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#routes">Routes</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-9">

    <div id="general">
        @* Section Gereral *@
        <h2 class="page-header">Gereral</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vel cu fugit vitae electram, </p>
    </div>

    <div class="active" id="words">
        @* Section Words *@
        <h2 class="page-header">Words</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vel cu fugit vitae electram, </p>
    </div>

    <div id="filetype">
        @* Section File Type *@
        <h2 class="page-header">File Type</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vel cu fugit vitae electram, </p>
    </div>

    <div id="routes">
        @* Section Routes *@
        <h2 class="page-header">Routes</h2>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, vel cu fugit vitae electram, </p>
    </div>

</div>

</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('body').attr("data-spy", "scroll");
        $('body').attr("data-target", "#side-nav");

    });
</script>
```

What i'm missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use javascript to add attributes dynamically to the `<body>` tag.

Add this script just to the page where the scrollspy is. When it is loaded inside the `_Layout`, the attributes will be added to the `<body>` tag.

**yourPage.cshtml**

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Designer";
}

@section scripts
{
    <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){        
                $( 'body' ).attr("data-spy","scroll");
                $( 'body' ).attr("data-target","#side-nav");  

            });
    </script>
}

[...]
```

**Shared \ _Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>

    [...]

        @RenderBody()       

    [...]

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", false)
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: i added your script to my page and its stayed the same..
I updated my post with my code maybe you notice my problem ?

Comment: Declare the scripts at the top of the document within scripts section. See my edit.